# OAuth2 Authorization with Wamp in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, wampserver, php-7, laragon

I am developing a Web API Rest in Laravel with OAuth everything is working when I use php artisan serves

```
Url: http: // localhost: 8000 / api / orders
```

[PHP Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYNiH.jpg)

But when I use Wamp / XAMP / Laragon and access by Postman

```
Http: // localhost / codedelivery / public / api / orders
```

Give this Error:

```
{"Error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. "}
```

[Using Wamp Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eepV.jpg)

Has anyone ever experienced this? And can you help me?

Comment: Oops, everything's quiet here. I had a small problem with Apache that did not read the Authorization parameter in the header, but it has already been resolved by adding "RewriteRule ^ - [E = HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:% {HTTP: Authorization}]" (without quotation marks) in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I had a small problem with Apache that did not read the Authorization parameter in the header, but it has already been resolved by adding

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E = HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:% {HTTP: Authorization}]
```

in .htaccess.